# self hosted vnext application

Tags: self-hosting, asp.net-core

I was wondering if I could refactor a self-hosted app (console app that starts and displays the URL of the webservices it provides) for it to work on pure vnext instead of owin.

The owin code is the following

```
namespace Selfhostingtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String strHostName = string.Empty;
            strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            Console.WriteLine("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);
            var options = new StartOptions();
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!addr[i].IsIPv6LinkLocal && addr[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IPv4 Address {0}: {1} ", i, addr[i].ToString());
                    options.Urls.Add(String.Format("http://{0}:5000/", addr[i].ToString()));
                }
            }
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(options))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Razor server is running. Press enter to shut down...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the record, I don't want to use the "k web" command line start. I want to fully package the vnext app as an executable file.

Instead of Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, the Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting should be used (same class as in the "k web" command definition. Keep in mind that Owin Startup expects IAppBuilder and the vnext expects IBuilder.

Comment: This can be useful: [How to Host ASP.NET in a Windows Service](http://taskmatics.com/blog/host-asp-net-in-a-windows-service/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET vNext you cannot build an EXE file, but you can definitely package up an app to be self-contained. Check out the `kpm pack` command that you can run in your app's folder. It will package up all the dependencies as well as generate the command scripts that you can use (instead of using `k web` etc.). Ultimately if you look at what `k web` does, it's just some shell scripts that end up running `klr.exe` with various parameters to indicate what it should start.

The project wiki has some basic information on the `kpm` tool's various options: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Package-Manager

Here is the command line help for `kpm pack` to give you an idea of what it can do.

```
Usage: kpm pack [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
  [project]  Path to project, default is current directory

Options:
  -o|--out <PATH>                  Where does it go
  --configuration <CONFIGURATION>  The configuration to use for deployment
  --overwrite                      Remove existing files in target folders
  --no-source                      Don't include sources of project dependencies
  --runtime <KRE>                  Names or paths to KRE files to include
  --appfolder <NAME>               Determine the name of the application primary folder
  -?|-h|--help                     Show help information
```